# Arduino Making Spiral

Tags: arduino, robotics

I have a robot sweeper that I am creating it detects walls and turns when getting to a certain distance so it does not hit. However the movements are pretty random and I would like the device to start out making a small circle and then growing to a larger one. It seems to be getting stuck in just one size circle with maybe a little growth. I created multiple size circle functions however it does not seem to be taking hold. Thanks ahead of time. Any help no matter how small would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<NewPing.h>
#define MOTOR_A 0 
#define MOTOR_B 1
#define TRIGGER_PIN 5
#define ECHO_PIN 4
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200

#define CW 0 
#define CCW 1 

const byte PWMA = 3; 
const byte PWMB = 11; 
const byte DIRA = 12; 
const byte DIRB = 13; 

NewPing sonar (TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE); 


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
setupArdumoto(); 
}

void loop() {
  delay(50); 
  unsigned int uS= sonar.ping();

  if(uS/US_ROUNDTRIP_CM>50||uS/US_ROUNDTRIP_CM==0)
  {
    forward(); 
    curve();
    //stopArdumoto(MOTOR_A);
    // stopArdumoto(MOTOR_B);
  }
  else if(uS/US_ROUNDTRIP_CM>=90)
  {
    smallerCurve();
  }

 else if(uS/US_ROUNDTRIP_CM>=110)
 {
   smallestCurve();
 }
  else if(uS/US_ROUNDTRIP_CM<20)
  { 
    //turnRight(100); 
    delay(500); 
  }
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
void driveArdumoto(byte motor, byte dir, byte spd) 
{
  if(motor == MOTOR_A)
  {
    digitalWrite(DIRA, dir);
    analogWrite(PWMA, spd); 
  }
  else if(motor==MOTOR_B)
  {
    digitalWrite(DIRB,dir); 
    analogWrite(PWMB, spd); 
  }
}
void curve() 
{
 driveArdumoto(MOTOR_A, CW, 200);
 driveArdumoto(MOTOR_B, CW, 150);
}
void smallerCurve()
{
 driveArdumoto(MOTOR_A, CW, 200);
 driveArdumoto(MOTOR_B, CW, 120);
}
void smallestCurve()
{
 driveArdumoto(MOTOR_A, CW, 200);
 driveArdumoto(MOTOR_B, CW, 100);
}
void forward()
{
  driveArdumoto(MOTOR_A,CW,170);
  driveArdumoto(MOTOR_B,CW,170); 
}

void turnRight(byte spd)
{
  stopArdumoto(MOTOR_B); 
  driveArdumoto(MOTOR_A,CW,250); 
}
void turnLeft(byte spd) 
{
   stopArdumoto(MOTOR_A); 
   driveArdumoto(MOTOR_B,CW,250); 
}
void stopArdumoto(byte motor)
{
    driveArdumoto(motor, 0,0); 
}

void setupArdumoto()
{
   pinMode(PWMA,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(PWMB,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(DIRA,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(DIRB,OUTPUT); 

   digitalWrite(PWMA, LOW);
   digitalWrite(PWMB, LOW);
   digitalWrite(DIRA, LOW);
   digitalWrite(DIRB, LOW);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's late but I think that your code rarely will execute `smallerCurve();` or `smallestCurve();` because if `uS/US_ROUNDTRIP_CM` is greater than 50, code in first `if` will execute and jump the code for `uS/US_ROUNDTRIP_CM >= 90` and `uS/US_ROUNDTRIP_CM >= 110` only when it was between 0 and 20 will execute different things. Take care of your `else-if`, once you have executed one block of code in an `if` you will jump over the `else`, and your first `else` take all the rest of your code.
In fact, a good compiler doesn't compile this `else`'s because they are unreacheable code.

And, moreover, you can improve your code with some simple things. Be careful with the function `drive Ardumoto` and don't use it so frequently, `forward` won't have time to move your robot. Use a delay between movements.